# fetch data from the SQL and display in an Interactive chart on the Web

Tags: visual-web-developer-2010

I am from Electrical background and currently trying to develop reports that my manager wants to view in his browser. 
Can you guys recommend what programming should I learn to 'fetch data from the SQL and display in an Interactive chart on the Web'.

Comment: We first need to know what version of SQL you are using.

Comment: SQL server 2017, version 14. Is there a dependency on the SQL version. Is it not possible to fetch data from older SQL's to web ?

Comment: PHP is usually a good language to get SQL data to the web. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp